how to format output with newlines using ast module
I am trying to generate some code using AST module. This is how my code looks like:
I would like to add new line after each key with proper formatting so that the output looks formatted.
my_awesome_properties = [
    (ast.Constant(value="key1"), ast.Constant(value="value1")),
    (ast.Constant(value="key2"), ast.Constant(value="value2")),
    (ast.Constant(value="key3"), ast.Constant(value="value3")),
]

my_awesome_properties_dict = ast.Dict(
    keys=[key for key, value in my_awesome_properties],
    values=[value for key, value in my_awesome_properties]
)

my_awesome_properties_assignment = ast.Assign(
    targets=[ast.Name(id='my_awesome_properties', ctx=ast.Store())],
    value=my_awesome_properties_dict
)

my_awesome_properties_assignment.lineno = 1


my_awesome_module_node = ast.Module(
    body=[
        my_awesome_properties_assignment,
    ],
    type_ignores=[]
)

print(ast.unparse(my_awesome_module_node))

This generates output as
my_awesome_properties = {'key1': 'value1', 'key2': 'value2', 'key3': 'value3'}
How do I add new line after each key with proper formatting so that the output looks like this with double quotes?
my_awesome_properties = {
    "key1": "value1",
    "key2": "value2",
    "key3": "value3"
}


Is this always code "just like this" in that you have a dictionary assigned to a variable or is it arbitrary code?

my_awesome_properties part of the code is always going to be fixed/static.

You might consider taking your string output and passing it to black.
import black

formatted_code = black.format_str(code, mode=black.FileMode())

I don't think that AST supports what you want directly.

I was trying to reduce the dependency on external modules but I looks like I must have to depend on some modules

By the way, I applaud your efforts to make sure that your generated code is well-formatted.  Whenever I had to write a code generator, I tried to make sure that the resulting code was well formatted and well documented.

Well, AST itself is generating the correct structure, its just not formatting it correctly as it doesnt exactly have any options to do that. Instead, you can do some quick post script modification to the dict to get the output you want.
unparsed_code = ast.unparse(my_awesome_module_node)

formatted_code = unparsed_code.replace(
    "{",
    "{\n    "
).replace(
    "}", 
    "\n}"
).replace(
    ", ", 
    ",\n    "
)

print(formatted_code)

This should work for your purposes.

this dont scale well if I have 1000s of lines of code.
